# Replacing some text in multiple lines - Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I want to change some text but not digits

```
<img src=“BISM1281.png” id=“Image3” alt="">
<img src=“BISM1282.png” id=“Image3” alt="">
<img src=“BISM1283.png” id=“Image3” alt="">
to
<img src=“101BISM1281.png” id=“Image3” alt="">
<img src=“101BISM1282.png” id=“Image3” alt="">
<img src=“101BISM1283.png” id=“Image3” alt="">
```

I want to add some text or numbers before BISM, but don't want to change anything after BISM.
Cannot use simple search and replace because “img src=“BISM” is using in different locations.

Comment: Replace `BISM` with `101BISM`? _"... because “img src=“BISM” is using in different locations"_ What's wrong with that?

Comment: And how can we distinguish the locations that must not be changed?

Comment: can be distinguish with "id=“Image3” alt" , only change BISM that has image3 tag.

Comment: Note that in your examples you have `“` and `”` for attributes - I hope in reality they are `"` like in `alt=""` at the end of your lines.

Comment: Yes @PeterKrebs they are simple html coding

Comment: Okay good! Can you give better examples? Because given your example you can just replace `src="BISM` with `src="101BISM` and you're done. Do you need a regular expression for replacing? You may want to add regex to your question's tags as well.

Comment: src="BISM is using multiple locations which I do not want to change. I only want to change BISM with id="Image3" and do not want to change numbering after BISM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `src="\K(?=BISM.+?id="Image3")`
- Replace with: `101`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
src="               # literally
\K                  # forget all we have seen until this position
(?=                 # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    BISM                # literally
    .+?                 # 1 or more any character but newline
    id="Image3"         # literally
)                   # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: @DroidReaders: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)